# url parameter becomes null after clicking button

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Here is my route:

```
  'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
         'upload' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/products/upload[/:products]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Products\Controller\Upload',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'uploadsuccessful' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/uploadsuccessful',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Products\Controller\Upload',
                            'action'     => 'successful'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),    
        ),
    ),
);
```

I am trying to call this route several times from different view scripts giving different `[/:products]` parameter.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('upload', array('products' =>'shoes')); ?>">Upload Shoes Product Image</a>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('upload', array('products' =>'trainers')); ?>">Upload Trainers Product Image</a>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('upload', array('products' =>'hats')); ?>">Upload Hat Product Image</a>
```

Here is my Controller code.

```
 <?php

namespace Products\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Products\Form\UploadForm;

class UploadController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $_dir = null;

    public function indexAction()
    {   
        $products = $this->params()->fromRoute('products');

        $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
        $fileManagerDir =$config['file_manager']['dir'];

        $this->_dir = realpath($fileManagerDir) . 
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
            $products; 


        if (!is_dir($this->_dir)) {
            //read, write, execute
            mkdir($this->_dir, 0777);
        }

        $form = new UploadForm($this->_dir, 'upload-form');
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $post = array_merge_recursive(
                $request->getPost()->toArray(),
                $request->getFiles()->toArray()
            );

            $form->setData($post);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $data = $form->getData();

                $this->setFileNames($data);
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('upload/uploadsuccessful', array('products' =>$products));
            }
        }
        return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
    }

    public function successfulAction()
    {
        $file = array();
        $flashMessenger = $this->flashMessenger();
        if ($flashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
            foreach($flashMessenger->getMessages() as $key => $value) {  
                $file = $value;    
            }
        }
        return new ViewModel(array('file' => $file));
    }

    protected function setFileNames($data)
    {
        unset($data['submit']);
        foreach ($data['image-file'] as $key => $file) {
            rename($file['tmp_name'], $this->_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file['name']);
        }       
    }
}
```

I think the idea is clear: for each `[/:products]` parameter I tried to make separate folder with given name in `$fileManagerDir`.

But, there is a problem. When I click on button upload  `($request->isPost() == true)` parameter `$products` becomes `null` and uploaded files don't go to appropriate folders. Also I am not able to redirect to successful action - the error appears "missing parameter" because $products is null.

Answer (score 0):

In your view script the upload buttons are href links. This will result in a GET REQUEST being sent to the controller and not a POST and no FILES will be present either. Unless that is, you are intercepting the click event with external JS which you haven't mentioned here. The route url's should be in the form action attribute. The submit buttons should be buttons not links (unless you are using JS not mentioned here). Make sure the form method is set to POST.

Something like:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->url('upload', array('products' =>'shoes')); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You'll need to deal with the dynamic action using JS or redesign your routing.